Adafruit gps breakout output encoded bytes not NMEA sentences
Using python 3.7, and pyserial readline on an Adafruit GPS breakout only outputs encoded byte data. How do i decode? It is not utf-8, or ASCII.
Here is a sentence:
b'[}\xc5\xc5\xf5\x9d\x9d\x8d\x9f\x8d\x9d\x97\xa3\x9f\x9f>\xa7\x97\x9f\x9d\x8d\xa3\x95\x8d\x8d\x99\xa7c\xa7\x9f\x91/\x9d\x9b\xa3\x91\x8d\x95\x93\xa7Q\xa7\x9b\xa7\x9f\x8d\xa7>\xa3\x8d\x95\xa7\x93\x8d\xa3\x9b\xa7e\xa7\xa5\x99\x97\xa36\xa7e\xa7\xa7\xab\x93
b'[}\xc5\xc5\xf5\x9d\x9d\x8d\x9f\x8d\x9d\x99\xa3\x9f\x9f\x9e\xa7\x97\x9f\x9d\x8d\xa3\x95\x8d\x8d\x99\xa7c\xa7\x9f\x91\x97\x9d\x9b\xa3\x91\x8d\x95\x93\xa7Q\xa7\x9b\xa7\x9f\x8d\xa7\x1e\xa3\x8d\x95\xa7\x93\x8d\xa3\x9b\xa7e\xa7\xa5\x99\x97\xa3\x9b\xa7e\xa7\xa7\xab\x93\x8d\xe5\xeb\xb7q_qY}F}\xa7\x99\xa7\x99\x9b\xa7\x99\x9d\xa7\x9f\x9b\xa7\x9d\x9f\xe6\x9b\x8f\xa7\x9b\x9d\xa7\x9b\x99\xa7\x9b\x95\xa7\x9d\x9b\xa7N\xa7\xa7\x9d\xa3\x93\x8f\xa7\x9f\xa3\x8d\x95\xa7\x9d\xa3\x99\x9e\xab\x9f\x91\xe5\xeb\xb7q_[ey\xa7\x9d\x8d\x9f\x8d\x9d\x99\xa3\x9f\x9f\x9f\xa7}\xa7\x97\x9f\x9d\x8d\xa3\x95\x18\x8d\x99\xa7c\xa7\x9f\x91\x97\x9d\x9b\xa3\x91\x8d\x95\x93\xe6Q\xa7\x9f\xa3\x9f\x9b\xa7\x93\x9d\xa3\x99\x93\xa7\x9d\x93\x9f\x8d\x9b\x97\xa7\xa7\xa7w\xab\x97\x95\xe5\xeb\xb7q_\xa6Wq\xa7\x93\x9d\xa3\x99\x93\xa7W\xa7\xa7e\xa7\x9f\xa3\x9f\x9b\xa7c\xa7\x9f\xa3\x9f\x99\xa7i\xa7w\xab\x9f{\xe5\xeb\x00'
10
b'[}\xc5\xc5\xf5\x9d\x9d\x8d\x9f\x8d\x9d\x97\xa3\x9f\x9f>\xa7\x97\x9f\x9d\x8d\xa3\x95\x8d\x8d\x99\xa7c\xa7\x9f\x91/\x9d\x9b\xa3\x91\x8d\x95\x93\xa7Q\xa7\x9b\xa7\x9f\x8d\xa7>\xa3\x8d\x95\xa7\x93\x8d\xa3\x9b\xa7e\xa7\xa5\x99\x97\xa36\xa7e\xa7\xa7\xab\x93u\xe5\xeb\xb7q_qY}\x9c}\xa7\x99\xa7\x99\x9b\xa7\x99\x9d\xa7\x9f\x9b\xa7\x9d\x9f\x0f\x9b\x8f\xa7\x9b\x9d\xa7\x9b\x99\xa7\x9b\x95\xa7\x9d\x9b\xa7N\xa7\xa7\x9d\xa3\x93\x8f\xa7\x9f\xa3\x8d\x95\xa7\x9d\xa3\x99\x1f\xab\x9f\x91\xe5\xeb\xb7q_[ey\xa7\x9d\x8d\x9f\x1a\x9d\x97\xa3\x9f\x9f\x9f\xa7}\xa7\x97\x9f\x9d\x8d\xa3\x95\x1f\x8d\x99\xa7c\xa7\x9f\x91\x97\x9d\x9b\xa3\x91\x8d\x95\x93NQ\xa7\x9f\xa3\x9f\x9d\xa7\x93\x9d\xa3\x99\x93\xa7\x9d\x93>\x8d\x9b\x97\xa7\xa7\xa7w\xab\x97\x9d\xe5\xeb\xb7q_\xb3Wq\xa7\x93\x9d\xa3\x99\x93\xa7W\xa7\xa7e\xa7\x9fF\x9f\x9d\xa7c\xa7\x9f\xa3\x9f\x9d\xa7i\xa7w\xab\x9f\xfa\xe5\xeb\x00'
The number is loop index I used to keep the output to 10 lines:
The code:
import serial
n = 0

ser = serial.Serial('COM2', 9600, timeout = 0.5)


while n<10:
    
    data = ser.readline()
  
    n= n+1
    print(n)
    print(data, flush = True)
    #Wait = ser.inWaiting()
    #print (f'State of waiting = {Wait}')
        
ser.close()

I am sure that the serial comm is working at 9600 baud. This is a windows 7 computer and the serial adapter works on other PLC communications.

Have you looked at https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps/circuitpython-parsing ?

I have looked at the circuit python docs. The encoding is not mentioned. I have seen a number of youtube videos where the user is getting an NMEA sentence directly from serial.serial.readline(). How?

This has been resolved. It was due to the use of an RS232 adaptor rther than a UART
